# Backbone form - custom template for a field - not submitting the value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pug, backbone-forms

SO i have a checkbox in my template which is (jade)

```
input(type='checkbox' name='flag' class='pure-checkbox onoffswitch-checkbox' id='myonoffswitch')
```

and i use this custom template form my flag field

```
  schema:
    flag:
      template: require ('templates/onoff-switch.hbs')
    threshold:
      type: 'Text'
      title: 'Threshold($)'
      editorClass: 'pure-input-1-3'
```

but when i submit my form the flag value is not set, its empty. I hope i have to bind my value to the checkbox value but i am sure how.

i tried

```
    input(type='checkbox' name='flag' class='pure-checkbox onoffswitch-checkbox' id='myonoffswitch' checked="{{#if flag}}checked{{/if}}")
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I created a Custom editor called Switch extending Backbone form Checkbox editor and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom form editor called 'switch' extending Backbone.Form.editors.Checkbox and use your own template in it. Something like

```js
Backbone.Form.editors.Switch = Backbone.Form.editors.Checkbox.extend
  tagName: 'div'
  className: 'onoffswitch'
  template: require('templates/onoff-switch.hbs')
```

Refer Backbone Forms https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms for more information on Custom editor and how to extend Checkbox.